# array transverse in ajax return

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I am storing Array in Js file , using ajax i get the whole array , who can i get transverse Array ?

```
$.ajax({
                type : "GET",
                url : "string-en.js",
                dataType : "script",
                 success: function(data) {

                    console.log('data is '+data);
                    //label=data;
                     $(data.d).each(function(){
                       alert(this)
                        });
                 }
            });
```

Return ::

```
data is a = {"Hi":"Hi","By":"By" };
```

Comment: Do you mean "How do I traverse the array" ?

Comment: use `console.log` instead of `alert`

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$.each(data,function(i,v){
        alert(v);
});
```

or if you data is `a` then

```
$.each(data.a,function(i,v){
        alert(v);
});
```

Comment: i have key/value pair array , using ur get i get Error" Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '26' in a = {"Hi":"Hi","By":"By" }; "

Comment: data is return which contains whole array

Comment: why are you using script as dataType .. if there is no particular reason then use `dataType : "json",` in your ajax ..and return your array as JSON.... that should work

Comment: or do i need to change datayatype:"script" , my js file contains only array??